# How to show rows even when no results in query

Tags: ms-access

I have to show the number of people needed during an hour shift.
I have two tables:

> ```
> Table 1: Time
> 0:00
> 1:00
> 2:00
> ...
> 22:00
> 23:00
> ```

And then there is the scheduled time and dates

> ```
> Table 2:
> 2:00 , 3people , 10-6-15
> 5:00 , 1people , 10-6-15
> 9:00 , 2people , 10-2-15
> ```

So what I want is:

> ```
> On 10-6-15
> enter code here
> 0:00 0
> 1:00 0
> 2:00 3
> 3:00 0
> 4:00 0
> 5:00 1
> 6:00 0
> 7:00 0
> 8:00 0
> 9:00 0
> 10:00 0
> 11:00 0
> 12:00 0
> 13:00 0
> 14:00 0
> 15:00 0
> 16:00 0
> 17:00 0
> 18:00 0
> 19:00 0
> 20:00 0
> 21:00 0
> 22:00 0
> 23:00 0
> ```

The problem is that it works fine if I don't set a date range, but the moment I do, it starts to only the ones with people on shifts.

My code is this:

```
Select distinct [Time] from [Table1] left join [Schedule] on
[Table1].[Time]=[Schedule].[Time] where [Schedule].[Date] = #10/6/15#
Group by [Table1].[Time];
```

And it gives me

```
2:00 3
5:00 1
```

Am I using the right Join? is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: shouldn't 9:00 be 2?  or is it zero because it's a different date?

Comment: It's 0 because it's a different date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you seem to be missing a few pieces of your query, but I think the problem is from limiting the date in the WHERE clause instead of the JOIN.

Try:

```
Select 
  [Date],
  [Time],
  sum(ppl) 
from 
  [Table1] left join 
  [Schedule] on
  [Table1].[Time]=[Schedule].[Time] and 
  [Schedule].[Date] = #10/6/15#
Group by 
  [Date],
  [Table1].[Time]
```

I think you'll have to do it in two steps, then.  Have one query limiting your `left outer join` table:
qry:

```
Select 
  * 
from 
  [Schedule] 
where
  [Schedule].[Date] = #10/6/15#
```

then a second one doing the `left outer join`:

```
Select 
  [Date],
  [Time],
  sum(ppl) 
from 
  [Table1] left join 
  qry on
  [Table1].[Time]=qry.[Time] 
Group by 
  [Date],
  [Table1].[Time]
```

Comment: I get "Join Clause not supported" when I try to use this. Is this a MS Access problem?

Comment: @arsarc did you copy the code exactly as it was written? Because you probably don't have anything name `qry` (or do you?)

Comment: No, I just tried to put from  [Schedule].[Date] = #10/6/15#  into the from statement instead of the where.

Comment: @arsac, try it in two queries instead of one